# SQL Server 2008 Activity Monitor Resource Wait Category: Does Latch include CPU or just disk IO?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2008 Activity Monitor, I see Wait Time on Wait Category "Latch" (not Buffer Latch) spike above 10,000ms/sec at times. Average Waiter Count is under 10, but this is by far the highest area of waits in a very busy system. Disk IO is almost zero and page life expectancy is over 80,000, so I know it's not slowed down by disk hardware and assume it's not even touching SAN cache. Does this mean SQL Server is waiting on CPU (i.e. resolving a bajillion locks) or waiting to transfer data from the local server's cache memory for processing?

Background: System is a 48-core running SQL Server 2008 Enterprise w/ 64GB of RAM. Queries are under 100ms in response time - for now - but I'm trying to understand the bottlenecks before they get to 100x that level.

```
Class                         Count     Sum Time   Max Time 
ACCESS_METHODS_DATASET_PARENT 649629086 3683117221 45600 
BUFFER                         20280535   23445826  8860 
NESTING_TRANSACTION_READONLY   22309954  102483312   187 
NESTING_TRANSACTION_FULL        7447169  123234478   265
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some latches are IO, some are CPU, some are other resource. It really depends on which particular latch type you're seeing this. [`sys.dm_os_latch_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175066.aspx) will show which latches are hot in your deployment.

I wouldn't worry about the last three items. The two nesting_transaction ones look very healthy (low average, low max). Buffer is also OK, more or less, although the the 8s max time is a bit high.

The AM_DS_PARENT latch is related to parallel queries/parallel scans. Its average is OK, but the max of 45s is rather high. W/o going into too much detail I can tell that long wait time on this latch type indicate that your IO subsystem can encounter spikes (and the max 8s BUFFER latch waits corroborate this).

Comment: Thanks.  I see ACCESS_METHODS_DATASET_PARENT, NESTING_TRANSACTION_READONLY, NESTING_TRANSACTION_FULL as having the highest counts.  (Top 3 encompass maybe 90% of the  waiting_request_count and wait_time_ms values)

Comment: Can you share the actual numbers? Count, sum, max?

Comment: And what build you're on, 2008 RTM, SP1, what CU isntalled? Basically, the output of `SELECT @@version`

Comment: Let's see if this formats properly:
`Class / Count / Sum Time / Max Time 
ACCESS_METHODS_DATASET_PARENT 649629086 3683117221 45600
BUFFER 20280535 23445826 8860
NESTING_TRANSACTION_READONLY 22309954 102483312 187
NESTING_TRANSACTION_FULL 7447169 123234478 265
`
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP2) - 10.0.4000.0 (X64)   Sep 16 2010 19:43:16   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Comment: Thanks for your help, Remus.  Looks like the somewhat-inefficient queries I thought were a small issue are small, but when multiplied by a million, eat up time.  I see a few queries that need optimizing and then load testing.